# Does Support Vector Machine takes vectors as features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, histogram, svm

I am trying to solve a problem with SVM and my X_train features are 2D with shapes of (256,1).
Is there any way to train a SVM model on a dataset with such features?
These features are histograms of gray-scale images.

Comment: Just map them to 1D features by concatenating the columns or rows. As long as you do so consistently for all your features it is the same as feeding in 2D vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible to train a SVM with histograms of gray-scale images but you need to transform them into representations with numerical values.

I would suggest to reshape the 2D array into a 1D array/list with 256 entries, so that the SVM can use it as a feature vector with 256 different numerical features, each representing a value of your histogram.

Comment: Thank you for your response however, I tried flatten() , ravel() and tolist() one my features but none of them worked. the error is: 
only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: @erfannazari try reshape()